# Call Button clickListener of activity from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have a button inside my activity which contain fragments. From one of the fragment I need to call button, button clickListener and pass an intent with extras to another activity. How can I do this? I searched a lot for this but couldn't find an appropriate solution for this.

Comment: I want to acces button inside my activity to pass intent with extras from one my fragment.

Comment: okay wait. I am trying those answers. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the onClickListener for the button in the activity:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // get the fragment from the fragment manager
    Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT TAG");
    Bundle extras = frag.getExtrasForNewActivity();

    /// Your code here this is for Activity
    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Second.class);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
});
```

and in the fragment, create a method like so:

```
public Bundle getExtrasForNewActivity()
{
    /// return a bundle with values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can contact your Activity through an **interface**:

- First, inside your Fragment:

  ```
  public interface ButtonCallback {

      //You can add parameters if you need it

      void launchAction();
  }

  //And when you want comunicate with Activity, launch call
  ((ButtonCallback ) getActivity()).launchAction();
  ```
- Then, your Activity must **implements YourFragment.ButtonCallback**, and override the method you hear the call from the fragment:

  ```
  Activity implements YourFragment.ButtonCallback{

     @Override
     public void launchAction() {
         //Todo
         //Your intent with extras...
     }

  }
  ```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can write the onclicklistener inside your fragment class as well.
Get the button object from your activity and set onclick in your fragment class onActivityCreated method like this ...

```
Button button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);

button .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /// Your code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is a bad practice as this would decrease the reusability of this fragment as it would always expect its parent activity to have a button with id "button1"

Comment: @Rishabh it depends on the requirement , if the fragment is only to be used with a single parent activity , this way would  be the shortest and easy code for a beginner