# How can i call a method from a a method in another class?

Tags: android

When I create an Android app, I  use a switch statement in a separate class to handle the behavior of multiple buttons. When I click a button, how can  I detect which button was pressed, from another class?

The other class is not  an activity class. Can anyone comment on the code below, so I'll better understand how to implement this correctly.

My first method in class A is

```
 public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.button1 :
                    GifView.mymethod(R.id.button1);
                final Dialog dialog1=new Dialog(context);
                dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

                Button finish1= (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.finish);
                finish1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog1.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog1.show();
                    break;
```

I would like to pass this button id to another class, which would have the business logic for handling all button clicks.

```
private void init(Context context) {
    switch(?????){
        case R.id.button1:
            setFocusable(true);
            gifInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.hen);

            gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
            movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
            movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
            movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
            break;
```

what can i do inside the switch statement?

```
public static int mymethod(int id) {
    int buttonId=id;
    return buttonId;
}
```

Comment: The correct way in Android is to have each button call a different onClick method. Any reason why you're going this route? Are you trying to create a whole bunch of buttons dynamically and programmatically?

Comment: I think that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34178641/4871526) can help you.

Comment: brother , i access this button click from another class. but when i wants to access this inside a method using switch statement from second class. which is the way to access this?@ Roy Falk

Comment: @RoyFalk: this `The correct way in Android is to have each button call a different onClick method` is not true.

Comment: thanks eveyone.this probleam is solved.

Comment: Akib. If the answer below solved it, please accept it. If the comment by Jose did, flag the post as duplicate.

Comment: @marcin-orlowsky correct is probably too strong in this case. For most  cases, especially the simple ones, I do not see the value of not following the Google tutorial. I googled this and people recommend this as a way to consolidate listeners and then give toy examples such as Log.d("button a pressed"); However, since I've been wrong before, could you explain or link to a use case for this? thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You could have a public static global variable and then inside your switch do something like:

```
public static int buttonClicked = 0;

...

switch(id){

  case R.id.button1:
    //doWhatever()
    buttonClicked = R.id.button1;
    break;
  more cases:
  break;
}
```

And then if you want you can create a getter method for `buttonClicked` so you can get the actual value whenever you want from outside the Activity.

This way you're **not passing the actual reference** of the clicked button, which could be problematic, you're just passing its `R.id`. If you do it like this, you won't be able to modify the Button you've clicked from outside the Activty, but you will be able to know what button was clicked through its `R.id`.

Comment: where is from (Switch(id)). is that code use in second class?@MIquel Parvez

Comment: All of the code I wrote should be inside the Activity. The switch(id) is when you switch to get the button that was clicked.