# Passing listview selected item from fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass the selected name from ListView to MainActivity from a Fragment but i am getting null pointer exception in onItemClick method.
Here is the code from the fragment:

```
getListText getListTextObject;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                nameListItem=(TextView) view;
                String text=nameListItem.getText().toString();

                getListTextObject.getData(text);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onAttach(Context context){
        super.onAttach(context);

        try{
            getListTextObject=(getListText) context;
        }catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement getListText");
        }
    }

    public interface getListText{
        public void getData(String s);
    }
```

StackTrace for the null pointer exception:

```
02-25 10:17:14.445 7388-7388/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.example.user.example.FragmentMain$1.onItemClick(FragmentMain.java:67)
                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post some of the stack trace for the NPE.

Comment: added some stack trace

Comment: @AlexTownsend i have posted the stack trace

Comment: @quick it is the full code. the code above is the full code of the fragment.. do u want me to add the code for activity too?

Comment: @NelsonJohn either your nameListItem or getListTextObject are null, causing the NPE here. Add a null check and a log statement for each to see which one it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is bad. Your Activity must **implements** the "*getListText*" interface. Then you can call since your Fragment to your Activity, like this:

```
((getListText)context).getData(text);
```

And recieve this data in YourActivity.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178641/4871526) is more complete. I think that can help you.

Comment: the code above is of the fragment not the activity and the getListText interface has been created in the fragment.